# How to remove property constraint from vertex label

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph

In Janusgraph 0.4.0 I want to remove a constraint I added to VertexLabel.

```
// Vertices
User = mgmt.makeVertexLabel('User').make()
displayName = mgmt.makePropertyKey('displayName').dataType(String.class).cardinality(org.janusgraph.core.Cardinality.SINGLE).make()
mgmt.addProperties(User, displayName)
```

I can get the list of property keys bound to the User vertex by

```
User.mappedProperties()
```

But now I want to remove this from the User vertex. I don't want to remove the property 'displayName' from the schema because I can do that easily by

```
mgmt.getPropertyKey('userId').remove()
```

But this does not remove the constraint itself form the Vertex.

Comment: Same issue for me too

Answer (score 1):

It is unfortunately not possible right now to remove schema constraints in JanusGraph. There is [an open issue](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/issues/1117) for this.

Comment: Did this ever get fixed in maybe another ticket or that the ticket didn't get updated with a feature enhancement?

Comment: No, this is unfortunately still an open issue in JanusGraph and as I wrote in the [linked issue](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/issues/1117#issuecomment-1090345677), this is simply because no one so far took the time to implement this. So, if you are willing to contribute, then that would of course be very welcome :)